# Errors when compiling first cython program

Tags: python, compiler-errors, cython

I am trying to start using cython and and attempting to compile my first program.  I have created a hello.pyx with the following code:

```
def show():
    print ("Hello World")
```

and a setup.py with the folowing code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [Extension("hello", ["hello.pyx"])]

setup(
    name = 'Hello world app',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

both in a folder that I called "cython programs" which is at C:\Python32\cython programs.  Cython is at C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\Cython.  However, when I run setup.py I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\cython programs\setup.py", line 10, in <module>
    ext_modules = ext_modules
  File "C:\Python32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 136, in setup
    raise SystemExit(gen_usage(dist.script_name) + "\nerror: %s" % msg)
SystemExit: usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

I'm guessing that I am missing something very simple but I can't seem to figure out what it is.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I take it you didn't give setup.py any arguments at the command line?

Comment: According to the cython documentation, you have to use the `build_ext` argument. If this is your problem, you should probably accept @Henry Gomersall's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `python setup.py build_ext`. That works for me.

Comment: Thank you, I think that I managed to run my setup.py successfully but there was still a problem. At first when I ran setup.py build_ext I got the error: error: C:\Documents and Settings\student\hello.pyx: No such file or directory.  After this I made a copy of hello.pyx into student and ran it again.  Then I got running build_ext;
cythoning hello.pyx to hello.c;
building 'hello' extension;
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat; I think that I need to link my C compiler somehow and I have downloaded MinGw but I am not sure what I need to change

Comment: You need to add mingw to your path. I actually do all my windows python development using msys: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS, which is a complementary shell for mingw and other useful unix tools. It makes the windows experience bearable! You *may* need to add some python paths in your windows path variable (I forget). Make sure you change your shell font from the evil default though! Once set up, it's great for using easy_install and so on, as well as actually running the python app.

Comment: I haven't tried msys but I did add mingw to my path.  After running again I got the following error: C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python32\include -IC:\Python32\PC -c hello.c -o build\temp.win32-3.2\Release\hello.o;
cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin';
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1;.  Also is there a way so that I don't have to make a copy of hello.pyx in student.

Comment: What's your directory structure? Also, what version of distutils are you using?

Comment: There seems to be a bug in distutils for newer versions of gcc: http://bugs.python.org/issue12641 . Try editing the set_executables definition in `c:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py` to remove -mno-cygwin. Also, I really do thoroughly recommend installing and using msys.

Comment: Ok I edited the c:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py file and now it worked.  Thank you for you help and I will take a look into msys.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a wild guess here...but I think it's the space in your directory name. I just spent a few minutes googling Cython & Distutils because I seem to recall one of the recommending you not use space in directory names when using them on Windows -- but I wasn't able to find the link I was looking for.

Try a quick test and just rename your 'cython programs' to 'cythonprograms' and see what happens.

Comment: Hmmm, I would think that it shouldn't matter as the path is enclosed in quotes... I think he just didn't give the script any arguments.

Comment: I thought the same thing at first, but it you just run 'python setup.py' with no arguments, you get the standard distutils help....but you don't get an exception...and he posted a traceback